# StreamWriter crashing after creating file

Tags: c#, file-io

So i have my write to file function and it will create the file if it does not exist, and it works but the problem is first time you run the code when the file does not exist it creates it and then crash the program

```
//writing file to Error.txt
string path = @err;
if (!File.Exists(path)) // if does not exist make it 
{
    File.Create(path);
    TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path); //crashes here after create
    tw.WriteLine(i);
    tw.Close();
}
```

Exception is:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: The process cannot access the file
> 'C:\Users\Desktop\TestStuff\error.txt' because it is being used by another process.

Comment: Can you show the exception that you're getting?

Comment: does `File.Create(path)` need to be there? I think that `StreamWriter` will create the file for you

Comment: Exception is self-descriptive. Your is file opened in some other program which is locking it.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev correction:  his file is opened in some the-same program

Comment: @SamIam his file is opened by `File.Create`

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267830/how-do-i-prevent-this-system-io-ioexception-when-copying-a-file

Answer (score 7):

You're using 2 file streams here without closing the first one.

get rid of `File.Create(path);`.  That method creates a file, [but it also returns a file stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d62kzs03%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which you're not storing and closing.

`StreamWriter` will make the file for you, but it can't, because your program has a handle on it.

Comment: The handle is there, because `File.Create` doesn't close the stream after crating a file

Answer (score 2):

You could make it easier by just using

```
using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)) 
{
    tw.WriteLine(i);
}
```

This would create, or reopen the file from position 0, and you can write to it like that